Turn off automatic adding of spaces to phone numbers
When I create a new contact and start typing its phone number, spaces are being added between the numbers, even though I never type phone numbers with spaces.
How can I prevent the extraneous spaces from being added when I don't need them? On a Windows OS I would go look into number formats/grouping, but I could not find the location of the equivalent setting in Android.

I agree that's it's a PITA, and one of many reasons I stopped using Google Contacts.  In the off chance that it helps you, it's a Google-specific problem.  Other contact apps don't experience the same problem.  So if you're willing to ditch Google Contacts, you won't have this annoyance.  But if you're committed to Google Contacts, hopefully someone will have an idea, else you can post an issue report on Google's feedback site, at which time they will promptly take action... ;)

@AmazonDiesInDarkness Are other contact programmes compatible with Google's cloud for the purposes of handling the contact list? Because if yes, that seems like a radical but viable potential solution.

Why does it matter so much?

@vicky_molokh I humbly don't know.  I don't use Google cloud, so I've never looked into it.

I have not used it, but DW Contacts looks lie it will do the job for you.
Screenshot does not show the numbers with spaces.

There is a review of contact apps here.  It mentions Contacts Optimizer, which I use.  It is amazing for organizing your contacts. However, its not really suitable as a Contacts App.
I am not associated with the app or the website
